# _trackEvent error in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I use this snippet to track some clic on a link without loading a new page but analytics didn't record the clic, do I made a mistake?

```
<a onClick="document.getElementById('divCode').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('lecode').style.display = 'block'; clic_code_bon();_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Clic', 'Telephone']);">
<span class="">Obtenir le numéro</span>
</a>
```

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Any errors in the console?  If so, what were they?

Comment: I don't see any error here is the link where the code is implement : http://www.commune-mairie.fr/noyon-60400/

Comment: For debugging, try replacing `ga.js` with `u/ga-debug.js` when you include your analytics code. Then some useful info will be logged to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function "clic_code_bon()" is apparently not defined on the page (and looking at the source, I don't see it). That's causing an error (in Firefox at least).  The error happens before the call to the Google API, so that call does not happen.

You have to click on the link in order to see the error (obviously).

Comment: Thanks I remove the "clic_code_bon()" and it works thanks a lot!